# how do I setup VisualGDB for Nucleo F091RC, for mbed local development?

Tags: mbed, nucleo, visualgdb

I'm following the mbed local development tutorial (http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/arm/mbed/).

I'm setting up VisualGDB, but at step 3. "New Embedded Project" there are no devices listed, and clicking "Download more devices" does nothing.

I need to install the toolchain for Nucleo F091RC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

support@sysprogs.com for VisualGDB support.

These fantastic guys walked me all through it.  Pretty complex.